# How do i connect to MySQL from .aspx script

Tags: mysql, odbc

I get error:

```
BC30807: 'Let' and 'Set' assignment statements are no longer supported.
```

with:

```
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
```

Comment: www.google.com/search?q=BC30807

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection();

myConnection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
myConnection.Open();
//execute queries, etc
myConnection.Close();
```

Where `myConnectionString` has a format like this:

```
"Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;"
```

Comment: thanks. However, i get this error now   BC36008: 'Using' must end with a matching 'End Using'.